# Draw an image once and then draw on it with finger (MonoTouch)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I can now draw a picture and then a draw with finger on it with the following code:

```
public override void Draw (RectangleF rect)
    {
        base.Draw (rect);

            using (CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext()) {

                // Draw image in context
                context.DrawImage (rectangle, imageToDraw.CGImage);


                 // Draw finger touch
                if (this.fingerDraw) {

                    context.SetStrokeColor (UIColor.Black.CGColor);
                    context.SetLineWidth (5f);
                context.SetLineCap (CGLineCap.Round);

                    this.drawPath.MoveToPoint (this.prevTouchLocation);
                    this.drawPath.AddLineToPoint (this.touchLocation);
                    context.AddPath (this.drawPath);
                    context.DrawPath (CGPathDrawingMode.Stroke);

                }
            }  
    }
```

however this brings me performance problems, it is very expensive to draw the image every time the user touches the screen.

how I can draw the image ONCE at the beginning and then only draw finger touch?

Answer (score 0):

Don't draw on the image. Put the image in a view that's underneath your `fingerDraw` view.

Comment: Thanks Ian for answering. Do you have some small example of that?

Comment: Create a `UIImageView` and add it to your hierarchy before you add this view that you're doing your drawing within. I'm sure you can find many examples of how to add a `UIImageView` in swift.